# Why my angular js data binding not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

javascript code:
I've written code using ng-repeat to show all elements of json object in js code but unfortunately i'm getting this instead of the values in my javascript object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvYbg.png)

```
var app = angular.module("myModel",[]);

app.controller("myController",function($scope){
  var employees=[
    {name:"Ben", dateOfBirth:new Date("November 23,1980"),gender:"Male",salary:55000},
    {name:"Sara", dateOfBirth:new Date("May 05,1970"),gender:"Female",salary:68000},
    {name:"Mark", dateOfBirth:new Date("August 15,1974"),gender:"Male",salary:57000},
    {name:"Pam", dateOfBirth:new Date("October 27,1981"),gender:"Male",salary:70000},
    {name:"Todd", dateOfBirth:new Date("December 3,1989"),gender:"Male",salary:45000}
  ];
  $scope.employees=employees;

});


html code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myModel">
  <div ng-controller="myController">Search : <input type="text" placeholder="Search employees" ng-model="searchText" /><br />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | filter:searchText">
          <td> {​​​​​​{​​​​​​emp.name}​​​​​​}​​​​​​ </td>
          <td> {​​​​​​{​​​​​​ emp.gender }​​​​​​}​​​​​​ </td>
          <td> {​​​​​​{​​​​​​ emp.salary }​​​​​​}​​​​​​ </td>
          <td> {​​​​​​{​​​​​​ emp.city }​​​​​​}​​​​​​ </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please replicate the issue in stack overflow code editor, because I tried just now and your code works just fine!

Comment: this is same code i have copy pasted and still getting the the output mentioned in the image above

Comment: If you're able to give a jsfiddle with the issue replicated we can help!

Comment: Hello @NarenMurali I found the  bug actually when I pasted the same code in jsfidle there were some hidden characters with unicode u+200b  in the binding expression after removing that I got the output Thanks :)